# Mudar link de dois links cujo id são iguais com js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Precisei duplicar um código de um link, cujo o id é o mesmo (não posso alterar, nem consigo na verdade). E preciso alterar o texto desse link. Fiz dessa forma:

```
document.getElementById("send").innerHTML = "Enviar itens";
```

Porem só altera o texto do primeiro link, e como dito, preciso alterar o texto dos dois links.

Código dos links:

```
<a id="send" href="rota" class="buy send">Send</a>

<a id="send" href="rota" class="buy send">Send</a>
```

Precisei duplicar pois não tenho acesso ao html "puro", eu chamo o conteúdo através de controles da minha plataforma CMS.

Comment: Adicione um exemplo do código e explique o motivo pelo qual você precisou duplicar esses elementos.

Comment: Editei lá @LeandroAngelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` suporta apenas node nome por vez e retorna apenas um único node, não uma matriz de nodes. Você tem várias opções diferentes:

Você pode implementar sua própria função que leva vários ids e retorna vários elementos.

Você pode usar document.querySelectorAll() que permite especificar vários ids em uma string de seletor CSS.

Você poderia colocar nomes de classes comuns em todos esses nós e usar document.getElementsByClassName () com um único nome de classe.

Comment: Consegui com o querySelectorAll(). Vlw!